# Move-only with drag & drop in a Flex tree

Tags: apache-flex

I have a tree (in Flex 3.5), and I want to use the drag & drop functionality, but I want to let the user only move nodes, not copy them. I tried listening for the dragOver event and change the drag event's action property if it indicates a copy operation, and also listening for the keyDown event and changing the feedback using the DragManager if the pressed key was ctrl, but to no avail.

Does anybody have another idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `dragEnterHandler`, `dragOverHandler` and `dragDropHandler` functions in Tree, since all are protected and quite simple, in order not to show copy feedback and not to allow user to copy via drag:

```
override protected function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    // ...
}

override protected function dragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: As I said, I have already tried to overwrite the dragOver handler and change the feedback, but it just didn't work, the feedback stayed as it was, i.e showing the "+" sign to indicate a copy mode, although I called the show(Drop)Feedback function on both the tree and DragManager (with the move mode).

Comment: Sorry, actually you need to override one more function - `dragEnterHandler`. I've just tried to left its internals empty - and it worked, there was no DragManager's feedback, which is allowing to drop.

Comment: Can you explain me what you did? Overriding the dragEnter event didn't work for me either...

Comment: The only thig I made in the derived class was overriding two functions with empty implementation. Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Is there any way to do that without using a derived class? I was sure you used event listeners to achieve the effect. I'm afraid overriding the handlers might have unexpected implications...

Comment: I don't know any other method to seriously change component behavior but derivation. And I don't see any unexpected implications concerning overriding handlers (except for unqualified and buggy code).

Comment: Overriding handlers on things other than lists is common practise it also allows you to check if the drag contains things it should or perhaps should not and then prevent the default behaviour to bubble up if need be.

its perfectly harmless and safe.

Its also handy for giving drag and drop to objects that don't conventionally support it (hint, nudge wink)

Answer (score 2):

Overide all drag handlers and add event.action = DragManager.MOVE See below:

```
    override protected function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragEnterHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function dragCompleteHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragCompleteHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragDropHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function dragExitHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragExitHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function dragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragOverHandler(event);
    }

    override protected function dragStartHandler(event:DragEvent):void{
        if(event.action == DragManager.COPY)
            event.action=DragManager.MOVE;
        super.dragStartHandler(event);
    }
```

This will make the list move only.. and wudnot support copy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending Tree class (unnecessarily), we can implement the same logic as in the above answers by adding our own event handlers for dragOver, dragDrop. Our event handlers execute **before** the default ones and can therefore modify the event attributes like action. So one example would be

```
<mx:DataGrid id="datagrid" dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" 
    dragMoveEnabled="true" dragEnter="datagrid_dragEnterHandler(event)"
    dragDrop="datagrid_dragDropHandler(event)" 
    dragOver="datagrid_dragOverHandler(event)"/>
....
protected function datagrid_dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
    event.action = DragManager.MOVE;
}
protected function datagrid_dragOverHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
    event.action = DragManager.MOVE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the class. In the answer by Sab Than, the base class handlers will be invoked and hence, overriding the action will become useless. SO before base class handler is invoked, we need to override the action type.